# Changing font in OpenStack Horizon

Tags: css, fonts, dashboard, openstack, devstack

I'm having troubles finding where the font used for OpenStack's dashboard Horizon is defined. I'm running VMWare Fusion with Ubuntu and a recent devstack installation on top.

I've tried this ( http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/topics/customizing.html ) and this ( http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/yum/content/dashboard-custom-brand.html ) guide, but besides all the paths not matching my installation for some reason (old documents?) and not even having any "openstack" under /usr/share I've hit a wall. There's probably a .css file somewhere I need to find.

I found a base.html and _stylesheet.html under /opt/stack/horizon/horizon/templates, but some of the guides tells me to look under "my dashboard"-path, and theres multiple .css files under /opt/stack/horizon/openstach_dashboard/horizon and /opt/stack/horizon/horizon/ and I'm not sure I understand the difference of all the, very siilar, paths.

I also found a "fonts" folder at /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/fonts, but switching out these fonts (.ttf, .woff, .svg, .eot) while keeping the same name changed nothing (still same font being used).

I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearantly changing the fonts in the folder mentioned above did the trick. I just needed the browser to reload the page and not just get it from the cache.